# Varaiable not passing as an integer in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a timer with the code below, but when I console log `time` in the tick function all I get back is `60` continuously , if I pass the `console.log` after `time - 1` I get NaN , which I guess means that time for some reason is not processed as an integer.

I cannot use state as using state for this timer re renders my components again and again which makes everything go crazy.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    var time = 60;
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this, time), 1000);
  }

 tick(time) {
    time = Number.parseInt(time) // This does nothing for some reason
    console.log(time);
    time = time - 1;
    if (time <= 0) {
      console.log('Hi');
    } return time;
  }
```

Comment: Porbably because "use strict", your `time` is defined within `componentWillMount`, but in `tick` `time` is undeclared, therefore it fails

Comment: @Pavlo it's declared as a function parameter already

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I am blind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I found your actual problem.

You need to store time in state. Add it to your initial state as 60, change the interval line to:

```
setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
```

and your tick function to:

```
 tick = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        time: prevState.time - 1
      }
    }, () => {
      if(this.state.time <= 0){
          console.log('hi')
      }
    }) 
  }
```

This way, time is tracked outside of your function scope and the value should always be correct. By passing an anonymous callback as the second argument to setState you ensure that the check only happens after time is decremented. The one issue I'd see with this is that React can be a bit funky with running setState and may not run every second, so this could end up being slightly imprecise.

Comment: This does the same thing , sadly.

Comment: @Sahil I changed my answer check it out

Comment: I've mentioned I can't use state , if I keep changing state it re renders my component again and again making it goes crazy , also when using state it pauses at time and continues. I would have used state if I had no other components

Comment: if setState is causing problems in your application then there are other issues with your application.

Comment: setState is the heart of react and is necessary to have a properly functioning react app. The problem with your function above is that the value passed in as time is not mutated, so it's always going to be 60 each time the function runs. This is easily solved by storing the variable in state. I urge you to take a closer look at your application and try to better understand react. Your application should be able to do this without dismounting/mounting your component (which is what it sounds like you're describing)

Comment: @Sahil if you have any questions I'm happy to answer them

Comment: also if you are absolutely hellbent on using react without utilizing state you just need to change the scope of the time variable, declare it as `window.app_time` or something, and reference it as such. No need to pass it around

Comment: I just had to make timer a separate component and import it in to the parent. Worked like a charm and no performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
componentWillMount() {
    var time = 60;
    this.interval = setInterval(
        (function() { 
            time--; 
            this.tick(time);
        }).bind(this), 
        1000);
}


tick(time) {
    time = Number.parseInt(time) // This does nothing for some reason
    console.log(time);
    //time = time - 1; //I removed this line
    if (time <= 0) {
      console.log('Hi');
    } 
    return time;
}
```

`componentWillMount` would look a lot prettier if you used arrow functions

```
componentWillMount() {
    let time = 60;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        time--; 
        this.tick(time);
    }, 
    1000);
}
```

Now you are changing time in the right place and sending it on to the function on each call.